# Ping6 link-local address with -I interface is throwing warning source address might be selected on device other than

Tags: networking, internet, ipv6, ping

OS: Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS

Ping6 to a link-local address with -I  option throwing a warning **source address might be selected on device other than <>**.

Can someone tell why would ping6 look for a different source address when -I is mentioned?

Output:

```
root@1-1:~# ping6 fe80::929:cbb4:d6ad:4498 -I vEth1
ping6: Warning: source address might be selected on device other than: vEth1
PING fe80::929:cbb4:d6ad:4498(fe80::929:cbb4:d6ad:4498) from :: vEth1: 56 data bytes
From fe80::250:56ff:fe8d:d8c0%vEth1 icmp_seq=1 Destination unreachable: Address unreachable
From fe80::250:56ff:fe8d:d8c0%vEth1 icmp_seq=2 Destination unreachable: Address unreachable
From fe80::250:56ff:fe8d:d8c0%vEth1 icmp_seq=3 Destination unreachable: Address unreachable
```